# Can I delete an account on my Nintendo 3DS XL without a password?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

My boyfriend was at Gamestop one day and a guy came in with a Nintendo 3DS XL asking for a certain price. The Gamestop employee said he couldn't do that. The guy said there were 40+ games downloaded on it. My boyfriend ended up paying for it, but his Nintendo account is still logged in and I can't log out of his account without a password. I wanted to know if it's possible to save the games but delete his account so that I can log into my own account.

Answer (score 3):

The digital purchases on the eshop are tied to the account. If you change the account you will lose access to the games.

As per [Nintendo Support](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43028):

> Digital game purchases are final, and cannot be transferred to a
> different Nintendo Account.
>
> - Please make sure that you are logged into the correct Nintendo
>   Account when purchasing or redeeming a game.
> - The game isn’t limited to the Nintendo Account that made the purchase. Anyone that uses the purchaser’s primary console can play
>   the digital games or DLC that have been purchased by that Nintendo
>   Account.